# virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net

hi i am comletly new to iis and asp.net i am trying to setup bugNET on a godaddy server. i created a virtual directory and once i tried to launch the site i get this error:

```
Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

here is complete detail of what i did.

hosting: godaddy
created virtual directory (child folder of root) - named: devbunk with these settings (anonymous access, directory browsing) 
that is all i can do to with iis on godaddy.

the error tells me that i need to turn the virtual directory as an application. godaddy doesnt let me do that... how do i do it?  btw, i have iis7 setup.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure this with **Godaddy Hosting Control Center**. log in to godaddy hosting center.
    Go to *Content* >> *IIS Management*.
    Click on the pencil icon to edit your selected directory.
    you will get a popped up screen with three check boxes. You need to check the one that says "*Set Application Root*".
    Click Ok and your directory will be configured as an application in IIS.

Hope this helps you and feel free to ping me if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need godaddy to do that, usually hosters do offer the ability to convert a regular folder as an application through their Control Panel, so if you have access to one search for that option. Other hosters give access through IIS Manager and Web Deploy to convert folders to applications as well, but it boils down to "you need your hoster to do that".
There are no ways for you to do that through Web.config or FTP or etc. I think Front Page Server Extensions did had a way as well. The best thing is contact your hoster and ask them what is the right way of doing this. Usually all hosters will allow you to create as many applications as you need as long as they run the same .net version.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties on Web.Config to ensure "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Do not copy"